# Rtools not currently installed

Tags: rtools

I am getting an error in R studio :
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

my installed R studio version :
RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

And Rtools version :
4.3 (4.3.0.1)

I tried to change the Rtools version but it did not work

Any Support please .

Comment: What were you doing when you got the warning message? Did it actually stop you from anything you were attempting? (asking because it is indeed a warning, not an error and warnings might be irrelevant depending on what you want to do).

Comment: As far as it seems , the codes are running normally , but for example , this warning shows each time I install a new package  .

Comment: Is there any solution so I can avoid this warning to show again as it might affect some other codes from working properly in the future .